# Ios Push notification : Null would like to send you notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, null, push, alert

I have a problem with notification push Alert. 
It shows me "null" instead Appname.
There is a screen shoot :

[image]

Do you have any idea why?

My product Module Name are not the same as the product name, is that it may related to the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check the "Bundle name" in your `info.plist` file.  The app will use that property first, and then the target name second for your app icon.  The name on your icon should be the same name that shows up in the notifications prompt

Answer (score 6):

Thank you mckeejm for your answer.
When I checked the info.plist, there was "Bundle display name" which was empty. 
It uses the "Bundle diplay name" at first, When I deleted it, it uses the Bundle name, and it's work now.

Comment: Great. Would you please mark as accepted by checking the checkbox on my answer? Thanks @kayla08